# I don't want to show pop error message when i disable switch using laravel

Tags: laravel

i am new at laravel ,when i enable switch popup message is working perfectly but I don't want to show error popup message when i disable to switch please how can i do that help me thanks.
Does Anyone have an idea please help me thank.

**CONTROLLER**

```
      public function featured(Request $request)
         {

        if ($request->is_featured) {
        $assignFeature = Product::where('is_featured', 1)->exists();
        if ($assignFeature) {
            $response['error'] = 'Product is already featured';
            return response()->json($response, 422);
        }
    }
    $id = $request->input('id');
    $featured = $request->input('is_featured');
    $featurediItem = Product::find($id);
    if ($featurediItem->update(['is_featured' => $featured])) {

        // form helpers.php
        logAction($request);

        $response['is_featured'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'product featured updated successfully.';
        return response()->json($response, 200);
    }
}
```

**ajax script**

```
   $('.postfeatured').change(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var id = $this.val();
            var is_featured = this.checked;
            
            if (is_featured) {
              is_featured = 1;
            } else {
              is_featured = 0;
            }
            axios
              .post('{{route("product.featured")}}', {
                _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',
                _method: 'patch',
                id: id,
                is_featured: is_featured,
               
              })
              swal({
              text: "Product is already featured",
              type: 'error',
              confirmButtonColor: '#4fa7f3',
            
            })
           .then(function (responsive) {
                console.log(responsive);
                
              
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use axios.post.then method to work after getting response success fully. Something like this

```
axios.post('/login', {
  firstName: 'Finn',
  lastName: 'Williams'
})
.then((response) => {
  swal({
          text: "Product is already featured",
          type: 'error',
          confirmButtonColor: '#4fa7f3',
  })
}
```

here you can use your response variable to check if is_featured true do something what you want

Comment: when i disable to switch it's showing popup message

Comment: what you exactly doing with function and when you want to show this popup

Comment: actually i want to show popup message that is disable switch when i try to click switch button for enable  it should be shown popup message Product is already featured